# How to display the bottom of an image?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a simple slide show image div. I'm trying to show the bottom of the image because always is showing the top.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="mainImg">
    <div>
        <img src="image1.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="image2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="image3.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery Code:

```
$(function(){
    $(".mainImg > div:gt(0)").hide();

    setInterval(function(){
        $('.mainImg > div:first')
        .fadeOut(2000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(2000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('.mainImg');
    }, 8000);
});
```

CSS Code:

```
.mainImg {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 500px;
}
.mainImg > div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.mainImg > div > img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

The code is working perfectly but the image is showing only the top part of 500px, and if the image have different height sizes how to do it?

[image]

Comment: max-height:100%; ?

Comment: Hve you considered to use *background* instead of **img**?

Comment: yes, I considered it, but is not what I'm looking for

Comment: What do you want to happen if the image is taller than 500px but not as wide as the viewport?

Comment: make the image fluid, it will resize depending on the parent containter's width. Try width:100%; height:auto;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest change is to make the image absolutely positioned and dock it to the bottom of the container.

You will see the difference in your fiddle sample moe clearly if you lower the height to 300px.

```
  .mainImg > div > img {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
https://jsfiddle.net/me3jdqc4/10/

Look at the first image, how an image with bigger height shows the bottom-center part of the image.

```js
$(function(){
 $(".mainImg > div:gt(0)").hide();
  
  setInterval(function(){
   $('.mainImg > div:first')
    .fadeOut(2000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(2000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('.mainImg');
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
.mainImg {
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  max-height: 500px;
  min-height: 500px;
}
.mainImg > div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 300px;
  min-height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*Remove this width*/
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainImg">
     <div style="background: url('http://www.viralthread.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/gfssgg.jpg') no-repeat center">
    </div>
    <div style="background: url('http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-140mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample1_l.jpg') no-repeat center">
    </div>
    <div style="background: url('http://www.bestmanspeechestoasts.com/wp-content/themes/thesis/rotator/sample-4.jpg') no-repeat center">
    </div>
  </div>
```

**OR**

Taking help from Mikael's solution, you can also try this:
https://jsfiddle.net/me3jdqc4/11/

Comment: sorry, I updated! I added the styles to div. Need to add to img.

Comment: i try that as well, but don't make change

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle of your question or something similar so we could edit it?